# Siam Latex template references broken on texmaker

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texmaker, journal

When I compile  Siams latex template  https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

I get broken references

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b5YKychD_w4HRfb6v1lJd8oEDH5wvW24?usp=sharing

I am using texmaker pdflatex -> bibtex -> bibtex -> pdflatex  which seems to work for other latex projects I've done.

This problem does not occur on overleaf.
Does anyone have any clue whats going on?
I checked my Miktex is up to date.

Comment: please don't use exernal links, but `pdflatex -> bibtex -> bibtex -> pdflatex` looks wrong, you should not need to run bibtex twice but you would normally neeed to run pdflatex twice after bibtex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Okay I tried  pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdftex -> pdflatex  instead same problem  also I think I need to post the output files for anybody to get what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Copy all the `.bst`  files from  the `bst` sub-directory included in the journal template to the working directory together with `main.tex`.

**(2)** Compile  with `pdflatex` (It will run twice).

**(3)** Run `bibtex8.exe` from the command line using `bibtex8.exe main` (I am using a 64-bit OS).

It should finish with

```
The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: sn-mathphys.bst
Database file #1: sn-bibliography.bib
```

(or use an internal shortcut of texmaker).

**(4)** Run `pdflatex` twice.

[image: b]

This is `main.tex`. Only `sn-mathphys.bst` it is needed to compile this example.

```
%%% FILE main.tex

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\begin{document}
    
\title{Article Title}

\author*{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file

\end{document}
```

Comment: When running bibtex I get the error 

 bibtex8: security risk: running with elevated privileges
I couldn't open file name `sn-article.tex.aux'
(That was a fatal error)

Comment: @Hao S  If you are compiling `sn-article.tex` you should run `bibtex8.exe sn-article` ( **without**  the `.tex` extension)